# How do I extract a value from quarterly cashflow using python and yfinance

Tags: python, yfinance

import yfinance as yf

ticker = yf.Ticker("AAPL)

q_cashflow = ticker_quarterly_cashflow

print(q_cashflow)

Some output below. How do I extract for instance the value of 'Change To Liabilities' on '2021-06-26' which is 3.070000e+08? Sorry I am beginning to learn programming. Thanks in advance.

```
                                            2022-03-26  ...    2021-06-26
Investments                                -6.390000e+09  ...  5.747000e+09
Change To Liabilities                      -2.139800e+10  ...  3.070000e+08
Total Cashflows From Investing Activities  -9.265000e+09  ...  3.572000e+09
Net Borrowings                             -1.751000e+09  ...  3.220000e+09
Total Cash From Financing Activities       -2.835100e+10  ... -2.939600e+10
Net Income                                  2.501000e+10  ...  2.174400e+10
Change In Cash                            -9.450000e+09  ... -4.730000e+09
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The way you write your question is quite sloppy. Please add enough details, format your code properly, and double check your question before posting to try avoid typos.

Answer (score 0):

It is just a Pandas dataframe. You can use the usual way that you use to extract a value from a Pandas dataframe. For example, `q_cashflow.loc[row_index_name, column_name]`